# How to run script on all worksheets, Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that deletes empty rows in Google Sheets. Currently it only runs on the sheet I have open; I want it to run on all worksheets in the document.

After a long time trying to apply code from other peoples questions, I just cannot seem to get it to work with my existing code.

Any answers are appreciated.

This is one snippet of code I tried to use but it would not run

```
function saveRange(){
    var tabs = [
        'Sample_tab_1',
        'Sample_tab_2',
        'Sample_tab_3',
        'Sample_tab_4'
    ];

    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var sheet=ss.getSheetByName(tabs[i]);
        var range=sheet.getRange('A8:AE47').getValues();

        sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, range.length, range[0].length).setValues(range);
    }
  }
```

This is what I have that works but only on the current sheet

```
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[2] == 0 || row[2] == '') {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};


function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Remove rows where column C is 0 or blank",
    functionName : "readRows"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the detail information about `not run` of `This is one snippet of code I tried to use but it would not run`? Because I think that `saveRange()` works for the sheet names of 'Sample_tab_1', 'Sample_tab_2', 'Sample_tab_3' and 'Sample_tab_4'.

Comment: Ditto - `saveRange()` works just fine. Would you please quote the exact error message that you are getting..

Comment: your clone from the sample will always delete rows in current sheet only, because you do not assign to delete rows in another sheet. You just assign the only active sheet with var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

Comment: Your snippet assign some sheets, but in your script, you just assign the current active sheet.

Comment: okay @user11982798 that makes sense, is there an action that instead of var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); that would get all sheets?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code snippet, but be careful, this will clear **EVERY** sheet in your current google Spreadsheet:

```
function readRows() 
{  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ttl = spreadsheet.getSheets().length;
  for (var a=0; a<ttl; a++)
  {
    spreadsheet.getSheets()[a].clear()
    //if you prefer to delete, please replace the above
  }
}
```

Combined with your script, it may look like this below:

```
function readRows() 
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ttl = spreadsheet.getSheets().length;
  for (var a=0; a<ttl; a++)
  {
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[a];
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();
    var rowsDeleted = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) 
    {
        var row = values[i];
        if (row[2] == 0 || row[2] == '') 
        {
           sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
           rowsDeleted++;
        }
    }
  }
};
```

Here I would like to give a modification:

```
function readRowsModify() 
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ttl = spreadsheet.getSheets().length;
  for (var a=0; a<ttl; a++)
  {
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[a];
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var values = rows.getValues();
    //if row 1 is header change i>0 to i>1
    for (var i = numRows; i>0; i--) 
    {
        var row = values[i-1];
        //if in this row, column c is 0 or column c is '' or column c is undifined, 
        //please correct define in this filter to delete row
        if (row[2] == 0 || row[2] == '' || row[2] == undefined) 
        {
           sheet.deleteRow(i);
        }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: +1 To this. In order to iterate over your sheets, a nice option is to use [getSheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It does delete all intended rows in the current sheet, but instead of doing the same thing on all sheets it just completely clears every other sheet.

Comment: I just follow your criteria row[2] == 0 || row[2] == '', but actually I don't know the content in each your sheets.

Comment: I have add the modify function in my answer, please check and review